# How to change access modifier of a method in a derived class?

Tags: typescript

I have two classes, one inheriting from the other:

```js
class A {
    protected do() {
        console.log("do");
    }
}

class B extends class A {
    public do() {
        super.do();
    }
}
```

What I want is to make the method `do()` public without duplicating the code of the base class or calling `super.do()`. Languages like C++ allow to just repeat the declaration of a method with the changed access modifier to accomplish that. Something like:

```js
class A {
    protected do() {
        console.log("do");
    }
}

class B extends class A {
    public do();
}
```

But that would be interpreted as method overload.

Is a similar approach possible in Typescript?

Comment: No, not even the `override` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to make the child class less restrictive without having to re-implement the method.

```typescript
class A {
    protected do() {
        console.log("do");
    }
}

interface B extends A {
    do(): void
}

class B extends A {}

const b = new B();
b.do(); //accepted
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQA4CcD2AXApsAQCbTHYAUAlIimvcNgHYTYj4B0I2A5hQETl+VANx1UAXyRSkASyYFMAMzDB80AELR8ADwJNiMeMnrlqALmgA3bLOLSkSUJBhbd+w3EQzGLXNAAjaABeaCZ8AHdNajEAjjNRaAB6JNU1dBIgA)

This performs interface merging:

1. `class Foo {}` declares the runtime type
2. It also declares the interface for said class which lives in ambient context.
3. `interface Foo {}` which is separate from the class will be merged with the interface definition for the class with the same name.

This allows changing the what the interface is. In particular here it declares the `do()` method which will thus always be public. Since the class `B` already has an implementation of `do()` inherited, there is no need to make a new implementation.